# How to iterate on a Firebase App after pushing it to the app store?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I put an app on the app store and now, I want to rework the app and change/add some functionalities. Since my local Project Folder can only be connected to one Firebase database and that database is now live, do I have to create a completely new project which is a clone of the original and work on that? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is, yes.

Long answer is....
You need different environments for your application. Production vs Lower environments.

Production is customer facing.
Lower is not customer facing.

Here is the thing, as you make changes to your application (pointing to lower environment), this app will then replace the current production application. When you release your application, you release your server updates as well. If you add nodes to your firebase, then they will be created respectfully. If you need to update / change names, you need to make sure you do this while the application gets updated.

But, yes, two separate databases. Its easy to update the app, just create a new project and point the app to the new API keys... done.

Answer (score 1):

You should have different Firebase projects for different environments, such as development, staging, and production.  It's usually not a good idea to develop against a project that your users are actively using, as you might make a mistake and disrupt their experience.